Yii2 advance issue with Docker and pretty Url
i've use Yii2 Advence Template and the official Docker image like describe in the documentation docker section
The project works with this address (for backend) http://127.0.0.1:21080.
But in my backend/config/main.php i've enabled pretty url like this:
return [
'id' => 'app-backend',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'homeUrl'=>'/admin',
//..
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'cookieValidationKey' => '***',
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
        'baseUrl' => '/admin',
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'baseUrl' => '/admin/',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true, // Cancel passing route in get 'r' paramater
        'showScriptName' => false, // Remove index.php from url
        'suffix' => '', // Add suffix to all routes (globally)
        // Compare requested urls to routes
        'rules' => [
            'home' => '/site/index'
        ],
    ],
],
'params' => $params,
];

But when i try http://127.0.0.1:21080/admin the css file or js file doesn't works (returns 404)
This configuration works fine on production, but how can i make it work also in my docker?
This is also my .htaccess in the project root
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web/$1

and this is my .htaccess in the backend/web folder
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php


Can you provide information on how you load your css/js ?

What is the port 21080?  What do you expect the IP address 127.0.0.1 to resolve to?  Does the end-user application see this URL, or is it only used within the backend?

@DavidMaze this configuration works on live server,  http://127.0.0.1:21080 this address come from official documentation.

The IPv4 loopback address 127.0.0.1 is incredibly context-sensitive, especially in a Docker environment.  It will mean something different on the host system, in a container, and on the system running the end-user's browser.  That's where the "how is this address being used?" question comes in: if the server-side application is trying to use it to connect to some other service, for example, it might work if both components are running directly on the host, but not in a container.

I use docker only on my pc not for server

How are you linking your css/js files? Are you using asset bundle publishing or are you linking static files? If you are using asset bundle publishing did you check the url of css/js files that the app tries to load?
